# Quickly find the selected vertices on my model

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, workflow, faces, selection-tools

In the *Edit Mode*, on the header, click:

*Select -> Select All by Trait -> Faces by Sides*

Then the new menu on the lower left of the screen says 4 vertices have been selected.

The problem is that I can not find those 4 vertices on my mesh. The 4 vertices must be in orange color, but I just can not find any orange color on my model, which has 2 million vertices in total.

[image]

So how do I quickly find the locations of those 4 vertices on my model please?

Comment: Numpad period quickly zooms in on selected vertices (or selected anything), which should do the trick if the four verts are all close to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have pressed the number 3 on the numpad, but it does not zoom in much, so it may implies that the 4 vertices are not close to each other.

Comment: Btw the menu doesn't show vertices selected, it shows which faces *to select* - in this case: quads ;)

Comment: @JachymMichal   So 4 means the vertices of a quad, not the vertices on my model. I think you are right. If you write your solution, then I mark it as the answer. I have a poor understanding on how to use "Select Faces by Sides".

Comment: No problem, answer is up including a gif (i'm a sucker for those ;)

Comment: @BlenderLake By the way, Numpad 3 is not supposed to zoom in (it might just happen compared to whatever you were viewing before), it's for changing the view to the right side, in the menu _View_ > _Viewpoint_ > _Right_.

Comment: @Nathan  and Gordon Brinkmann,  I am sorry about my mis-typing. I am using a laptop which does not have a numpad, so I have to press "~" and then "3" to view selected vertices, instead of the period key....  And I have tested whether using "View Selected" can actually find the selected vertices. You can find more details from my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The menu doesn't show vertices *selected*.
It shows which faces *to select* - faces made by four vertices.

There are no such faces in your mesh, so no vertices are selected.
(hence the infobar in lower right showing (0/704 248)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To completely answer my own question, I have explored another example:

*Select -> Select All by Trait -> Non Manifold*

Then 26 vertices out of 800,000 are selected. Now, let's use "*View Selected*" and zoom in to find those selected vertices. But can I find them?

[image]

By the way, I am using a laptop which does not have a numpad, so I have to press "~" and then "3" to view selected vertices, instead of the period key. And I have to use Ctrl and "+" to zoom in, instead of just "+".

From the video recorded above, I could not find any selected vertices, even using "*View Selected*" and zoom in.

**My solution**:

After selecting "*Non Manifold*", on the header, click:

*Select -> Select More/Less -> More*

[image]

Then repeat this action for several times until I see the orange selected color appeared on the head:

[image]

Now I know where those 26 vertices come from.